# Transducers for sensing brain waves which can be made at home?

Tags: sensor

I am in my evil mad scientist mode right now, partly due to the finals tomorrow. Yesterday I was reading about those new consumer devices which allow one to sense brain waves. Somebody even interfaced those with an arduino (man they are everywhere) and a computer.

This got me thinking, can I make such a device at home? I know they could be bought for relatively cheap right now but I am in India and most of them cost more than I would ever have in one year.

Does anyone know of any diy transducers which could sense brianwaves using parts I could acquire easily? I am not looking for neurofeedback. That can be dangerous (for no openEEG for me). I just want to sense, not give signals back to my brain.

Comment: Sorry for not helping, but let me reassure you that it can be done. I've seen a system using DIY transducers at one of the tech fairs in my country. Unfortunately, I don' have any specifics.

Comment: @andre, I was quite sure this could be done as I have seen the openEEG project which is doing it. But their website is a mess and its an ongoing process to make something very big. But any pointers to things that might make me get closer would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neurofeedback doesn't push signals back into your brain - the feedback is you looking at the signal or hearing the noise that's created by reading the waves.  No signals return from the hardware direct to your brain so you're perfectly safe with something like OpenEEG - the electrodes are entirely passive (apart from signal amplification, but still no transmission into your head).

I was semi-involved with electrodes for a fun project that wanted to measure electrical signals controlling muscles so they could turn a servo (bionic arm baby!).  I didn't do the procurement but one of the other people in the group said he got a good deal on disposable electrodes from the internet.  Most of the OpenEEG electrodes are not designed to be disposed, so their build quality is a bit better and (I think) doesn't require the yucky gel.

In general, the electrodes are thin silver plates with wires attached.  That's pretty much it - just have two so you can create a differential signal.  Be warned though: the primary problem we had was 60Hz interference from power lines.  The electrode cable made a decent enough antenna to pick up all of the interference around.  I suppose in India it will be 50Hz?  I'm not sure and too lazy to read Wikipedia at the moment, but it required some filtering because the signals we wanted were in the millivolt range.

Good luck!

Comment: I half suspected I was wrong with neurofeedback. But the site is somewhat messy and I didn't do my research. But right now I am looking for a concise tutorial or booklet which would walk me through the theory and practice of making these electrodes. I did find some designs with open eeg but everything is scattered everywhere. Maybe when my exams are completed then I would get some time to plow through the website. Maybe my mistake was to first go to the warnings page.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an EEG, but my experience building an EKG circuit from scratch might help you a bit. (Not sure if EEG is easier or harder). A few old OP27's configured as an [instrumentation amp (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier) on a breadboard provided sufficient gain to get from sensors to an output comparator, which drove an LED. The power source was a 9V battery, both for safety and reduction of 60Hz noise input. The sensors were nothing more complicated than leads soldered onto two shiny new pennies. For contact gel, a mixture of alcohol hand-sanitizer with a little baking soda did the trick. Just the two sensors feeding the differential input of the instrumentation amp (and the usual fiddling with resistor values) was all it took to make the LED blink in sync with my actual heartbeat.  It was a quick, cheap, satisfying hack.

For an EEG, you obviously want a more analog output than just the on/off from a comparator, so you'd want to run the amplifier output into an ADC. I'd say try running the signal into a PC sound-card input, but not sure that PC sound inputs have much response in the frequency range you want, which is probably in the 1Hz to 40Hz range. You'd probably also want more than a single pair of sensors. If you stick with a 9V battery for power, you will have a very hard time electrocuting yourself, and won't be able to drive any signals into your neural nets.

btw, if you're really worried about signals going *into* your brain, the only thing that does *that* AFAIK is "transcranial magnetic stimulation". You won't build that by accident.

Comment: Upvote for ingenuity, details, & safety pointers. This is one I need to try.

Comment: although this is not what I have been looking for, I can try this in the mean time. Would look for other ways to make my gel as I don't know what exactly you are talking about.

Comment: @Rick_2047 - here in the US, in just the last couple of years, you can hardly turn around without seeing these alcohol-based hand sanitizer dispensers everywhere. you can usually get your own personal supply in a pharmacy for very little money. They even gave some out free where I work, which is how I came by it. The stuff evaporates very quickly so I mixed baking soda (NaHCO3) into it. Probably baking soda and water would work just as well.